# Connect to SQL Server and SQL Server CE database in same code

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-ce

Let me preface this by saying I'm kind of new to C# and database implementation. I'm trying to create some code that will connect to a database, but the type of database can vary between SQL Server, SQL Server CE, and maybe later on MySQL or something like that. I'm trying to implement the code using the `DbConnection`, `DbCommand`, `DbDataAdapter`, etc classes that is the base class of all these types of database classes. However, I am having difficulty trying to set this up.

I've tried using `DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase("connectionString")` but it wants me to put `connectionString` the the `app.config` file, but I don't want the program to be set up that way.

I've also tried `DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(providerStr)` but in order to get the correct `providerStr`, I need to know which database I'm using.

Basically I want it so that no matter what type of database I am using, the code will still work. Is there any easy way to do this or is it possible? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have any controls over the servers?  My preference in this setup is to connect to a single server as the primary data source and use linked servers to connect the other datasources.  Leaves you able to access the data from anywhere through the linked server and only connecting to one server.  MySQL and MSSQL syntax differs, this would only leave you using MSSQL (assuming thats where you set up the linked servers)

Comment: I agree, that is the only way I can think its even possible to link them in the same connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've come to the conclusion that there is no way to do this without exactly specifying the type of database to connect to. So my answer was to add an enumeration of the varying types of databases and use `DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(providerStr)` to create a `DbProviderFactory` instance. Here's some of the code if anyone is interested or trying to do what I'm doing.

```
    DbProviderFactory dbFactory;

    private DatabaseTypes m_dbType;
    public DatabaseTypes DbType
    {
        get { return m_dbType; }

        set 
        {
            m_dbType = value;
            dbFactory = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(DatabaseProvider.GetDatabaseProvider(m_dbType));
        }
    }
```

In another file I have the enumeration and DatabaseProvider class defined. It looks like this:

```
    public enum DatabaseTypes
    {
        SQL,
        SQL_CE
    }

public static class DatabaseProvider
{
    private const string SQL_Provider = "System.Data.SqlClient";
    private const string SQL_CE_Provider = "System.Data.SqlServerCe.3.5";

    public static string GetDatabaseProvider(DatabaseTypes dbType)
    {
        switch (dbType)
        {
            case DatabaseTypes.SQL_CE:
                return SQL_CE_Provider;

            case DatabaseTypes.SQL:
            default:
                return SQL_Provider;
        }
    }
}
```

Now if I want to add another database type, I'll just add it to the enumeration, get add another provider string, and put another case in the switch statement! All I need to do now is figure out how I am going to handle the queries.